# how to fix that quick.db doesn't make a negative output

Tags: discord.js, quick.db

I am doing an economic system at my discord bot. It went well but when I use some subtract command or withdraw command or your balance will be subtract
it got to negative number like I minus my balance to 50 but my balance is only 25 now my balance is now -25 how to fix it??

My balance file:

```js
module.exports ={
    name:'bal',
    description: "bal for user",
    execute(message, args, Discord, db){
    const target = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author
    const targetid = target.id
        
    if(db.get(`user_${targetid}.bal`) === null){
        message.channel.send('you need to create an account')
    }else{
        let bal = db.get(`user_${targetid}.bal`)
        let bank = db.get(`user_${targetid}.bank`)     


        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`${target.username} BALANCE`)
            .setColor('GREEN')
            .setDescription(`coins: ${bal} Cheese Coins \nbank: ${bank} Cheese Coins`)

        message.channel.send(embed)

    }
    }
}
```

My substract file:

```js
module.exports ={
    name:'sub',
    description: "sub",
    execute(message, args, Discord, db){
    const hey = message.mentions.users.first()
    const number = args[1]
    
    if(!hey){
        message.channel.send('Mention someone or ill take yours')
    }else if(!number){
        message.channel.send('Put a number, take it or leave it')
    }else{
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Poor speedrun Any%')
        .setColor('YELLOW')
        .setDescription(`Total of ${number} money has revoked been from ${hey}, **SAD ${hey} NOISES**`)

    db.subtract(`user_${hey.id}.bal`, number)

    message.channel.send(embed)
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify if the userbalance is less than the amount you trying to substract.

```
const userbalance = db.get(`user_${hey.id}.bal`);
if(userbalance < number) return;
db.subtract(`user_${hey.id}.bal`, number)
```

Comment: ok ok ima test it ill report you what is the problem thonks man :>>

Comment: it works man thank you very much I knew it StackOverflow is the heaven of codes XD

Comment: Glad to help, if this answers your question, mark it as an answer.